# Where's Brother Vernan's hidden lair?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-falskaar

In the Falskaar quest, Dreams in Oblivion, [I am tasked to search for Brother Vernan's hidden lair (a hidden room or cave of some sort)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tK4pR.jpg).

However, there is no quest marker, and I've looked all over the nearby vicinity but can't seem to find it. [Like Brother Vernan, I am not a man of patience](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUOyT.jpg). Can anyone point me to where Brother Vernan's hidden lair is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The hidden lair is a hidden sewer entrance between the garden and the little pond at the Priory.

[image: screenshot]

If you have mods or modified .ini settings for lusher/longer grass, the hideout entrance may be completely covered in plants (unlike the screenshot above). It may be more visible, if you look down with the 3rd person camera zoomed out directly above your head.

Comment: Yeah, and it's good that galacticninja replaced my original with a better one.

Comment: @Anon who suggested [this edit](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/revisions/125564/3): Are you sure that there's a quest marker? Last time I played this mission there was no quest marker. Could this be due to a later Falskaar update? I played this quest with the first released version of Falskaar.

Comment: @galacticninja I'm not sure of that. There's no quest marker, but there *could* be a "pointer to the lair's entrance" in Local view, where doors are seen. Someone should check that and possibly take a screenshot

Comment: I think that there is no quest marker because you are supposed to ask the priors where he might be and they give you the hints

Comment: A few days ago I installed Falskaar (latest version) and there is no quest marker, nor is it visible on the local map.